# How do I make it so that I can directly connect to the virtual machine from my computer?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine

From my computer I want to connect to a virtual machine that is running on a server:

> my-pc --> (server --> vitual-machine)

First, I connect to the server:
`ssh name@server`

Only then do I connect to the virtual machine:
`ssh name@vitual-machine`

How do I make it so that I can directly connect to the virtual machine from my computer?

Comment: Ask your local administrator. We don't know how stuff is routed in your network.

Comment: Depends what virtual machine you are using. Tell us by editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can just add a hopping step (jump host).

```
ssh -J user@server user@virtual-machine
```

Obviously this is not a direct connection per se, but it skips doing the ssh command on the server.

Whether and how a direct connection is possible, depends on the makeup of the virtual machine. E.g. if it is directly visible on the network with its own IP. Typical connection modes are listed [here](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Network_Configuration_in_VirtualBox#overview_table_of_access_options) (not limited to VirtualBox).

Comment: Thank you, it's working.